# How to get title name of console using python?

Tags: python, windows, console, command-line-interface, title

Is there any change of getting console title name instead of renaming it?
I know that I can use i.e. ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW to set new title of the console but I just want to get title name and do not set new title.

Answer (score 0):

Unsurprisingly, the companion function is `GetConsoleTitleW`.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `GetConsoleTitleW` is not enough to obtain the console title. Instead, you first need to create a buffer to hold that data and pass that. Then, return the buffer's value.

The following function will return the console title:

```
import ctypes

def get_console_title():
    BUF_SIZE = 256
    buffer = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(BUF_SIZE)
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleTitleW(buffer, BUF_SIZE)
    return buffer.value
```